# get data from DialogFragment to the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a Fragment in a Viewpager.
I am opening a DialogFragment from it which is taking the data from a ParseQuery. So far so good. Toast the clicked item also works.
I am trying to setText for a TextView in the Fragment that the dialog is called from without success... Anything i try just doesn't work - Intent, Bundle nothing... Going crazy with it already :)
I am not familiar with Interface and Callbacks, if that is needed. I don't know...
Thanks a lot in advance for any answer!!
Want to mention that i am not an advanced programmer, so any detailed explanation will be blessed :)

Here is the DialogFragment code - what i am trying to take from it and set to the TextView is `pType.get(position).toString()`

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ParseQuery<PropertyTypes> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PropertyTypes.class);
    query.whereExists("propertyType");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<PropertyTypes>() {

        @Override
        public void done(final List<PropertyTypes> pObjects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                final ArrayList<String> pType = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (PropertyTypes j : pObjects) {

                    pType.add(j.getTypeName());

                }

                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pType);
                mylist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        getDialog().dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pType.get(position).toString() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Intent...?
                        // Bundle...?
                    }
                });

            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I made some typos there... Sorry for it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `setTargetFragment()` method for this. For example, use `setTargetFragment()` while calling your Dialog Fragment

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CODE);
dialogFragment.show();
```

and on your `onItemClick()` inside DialogFragment do this

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pType.get(position).toString() + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putStringExtra("yourKey", yourStringValue);
                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                        getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    }
                });
```

and you can get that string value in your `onActivityResult()` of your calling/target Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                   if(data!=null){
                        // set value to your TextView
                        textView.setText(data.getStringExtra("yourKey"));
                    }
                } 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank u so much! ok, will try it and see how it goes - will write if it went through..

Comment: Hey there - that did it! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi Mukesh. Yes it did! Thanks a lot again :) I guess as i go with the app, a lot more question will pop up :))

Comment: how do you override onActivityResult in a fragment?